# Each background middle img repeated vertically must appear full size to match bottom img

Tags: html, css, web

I spent more than 10 hours trying to find a solution to my problem (most answers were on Stack Overflow) but nothing seems to be exactly what I need and I may not be experienced enough to adapt a solution to my own issue.

So, I made a picture where I want text to appear on my website. But only inside that picture (frame). So I cut it in 3 parts and made it tileable.

The 3 images and what it should look like (notice the fact there are transparent parts):
[image: The 3 images and what it should look like (notice the fact there are transparent parts)]

So what I simply did in html/css : I made 4 divs, one for the top part, one for the middle part, one for the bottom part and one for the page content (text or images).

The middle part has a **repeat-y**. So here is the result when the text is longer than the middle part (242px):

[image: Middle image is cropped]

In the above image, there are 2 middle images (the first one and the repeated one, but it's cropped automatically). Depending on the length of the text, it is cut at the wrong location and it messes everything. It must fit perfectly each time, and if it's longer than 242 pixels (height of the top image), it doesn't fit exactly.
I would like the div to show the entire "middle.png" WHEN repeated or to make the div lengths = (242 pixel * amount of "middle.png")

Help me please, if possible with pure CSS/HTML. I know close to nothing in PHP, and even less in JS (and even LESS in Jquery :D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for cannot be done in pure HTML/CSS (as far as I know). You need to have some calculations on the div height, and apply appropriate logic based on that.

Basically you need to check if the `div height` is divisible by **242**. If it is, cool, everyone is happy, if not, then set the height of the div, to be the **first next number divisible by 242.**

Pure JavaScript

```
<script>
r(function(){

        var div = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0];
        var divHeight = div.offsetHeight;

        if (divHeight % 242 != 0) { // checks if height is divisible by 242
            div.style.height = ""+(Math.ceil(divHeight / 242) * 242)+"px"; // set height as the next number divisible by 242
         }
    });
    function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}
</script>
```

[WORKING PURE JS EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ubeodvj5/3/)

**OR** if you're more familiar with **jQuery** framework it would look something like this:

```
    //First, add the jQuery library
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Then add the code that does all the work

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
              var div = $('.myDiv');
              var divHeight = div.height();

              if (divHeight % 242 != 0) { // checks if height is divisible by 242
                    div.height(Math.ceil(divHeight / 242) * 242); // set height as the first next larger number divisible by 242
              }
         });
   </script>
```

[WORKING JQUERY EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ubeodvj5/1/)

Comment: That's what I concluded, that the length had to be calculated but maybe there are some things in CSS that do it automatically. Your solution can be done in php? since you propose jQuery, it may aswell be done in php, no? (I know almost only CSS/Html but I read lots of PHP so it would be easier for me to implement than JS or jQuery)

PS: Although I don't doubt of your solution, I don't understand how the jsfiddle can show me it is working. Sorry I'm not used to this stuff

Comment: OK, the easiest would be for you to just paste the entire <script> tag from pure JS solution anywhere in the html on the page that needs the calculation. You can't do it in PHP, since PHP is server side language (it executes on the server, before the content is rendered at all). It can't be done in CSS.

Comment: The jSFiddle shows that the initial height of the red div is 150px (upper right css code), but you'll notice that final height of the div, after the JS does its calculations, is 242px; You can test that by setting the initial height to 300px for example, click run, and the final height will be 484px (2*242).

Comment: Ok thank you, I see for the jSFiddle now! I didn't notice it was more than 150px.

"You can't do it in PHP, since PHP is server side language (it executes on the server, before the content is rendered at all)."
But jQuery too, right?

(If forced, I'll go the javascript way but I prefer server side in case it's disabled on the browser. Btw I simply need to put the code snipet into  my page?)

Comment: **What must be modified to make it work, please?** Do I add it inside the middle part div? I'm really not used to JS basics so I don't really know how to make it work

Comment: The only way you could do it on server side is to know, how long the content is, what font is being used, take all the styles/paddings/line-heights into account, and somehow calculate the height of content based on that. It could perhaps be done, but I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: Add it anywhere inside your html code. Best if you could paste it just before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: Ok, I was trying but it didn't work. But since you didn't give more details, I supposed it was easy :P So I tried to find why it didn't work. In fact, I replaced "mydiv" by the div ID but I saw getElementByClass so I added a class to my div and it worked. So I changed getElementsById and removed the class I just added.
And it seems to work super fine.
So thank you, a lot.

Can you tell me what is the benefit of doing it in jQuery please??

Comment: (I should have looked at the jsfiddle -__-)
By the way GetElementsById doesn't work in fact, dunno why. And it doesn't behave the same way in chrome or firefox

Comment: Well, the benefit would be, really, the simplicity of the code, readability and cross browser compliance. jQuery selectors are much more simple to read, write and maintain than plain JS. jQuery (like any other framework), expands on the JavaScript and adds convinient methods for selecting objects, changing object properties, animations etc etc... 90% of modern frontend design runs jQuery in some form.